# Jms message failure with Retry advice send response to fail channel and again pass to successful channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Below is the config

```
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="someId" channel="inputChannel"
                                  connection-factory="${connection.factory}"  destination="queue">
        <jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="T(Boolean).TRUE"/>
                <property name="successChannelName" value="afterSuccessDeliveryMessageChannel"/>
                <property name="onFailureExpression" value="T(Boolean).FALSE"/>
                <property name="failureChannelName" value="failureChannel"/>
            </bean>
            <bean id="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession"
                  class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
                <property name="retryTemplate">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                        <property name="retryPolicy">
                            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                                <property name="maxAttempts" value="5"/>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="recoveryCallback">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                        <constructor-arg ref="failureChannel"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am retrying message 5 times and then using recoveryCallBack logging message to some DB.
It works fine retry 5 times and call **failureChannel** channel but once it calls the failureChannel  then again it pass to **afterSuccessDeliveryMessageChannel**.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?
I am expecting once it failed it should go **failedChannel** NOT again back to **afterSuccessDeliveryMessageChannel**.

Comment: That makes no sense, unless somehow the downstream flow on the failure channel is routing it back; enable DEBUG logging so you can see how the messages flow.

Comment: I have enabled the DEGUB logging it simply show postSend (sent=true) on channel 'gfailureChannel' and next line it shows PreSend on channel 'afterSuccessDeliveryMessageChannel.

Comment: Also i was looking into ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice class it has @Override
 protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception  which checks for onSuccessExpression, I THINK that could be the issue in my case onSuccessExpression is not null so it will call the afterSuccessDeliveryMessageChannel. I am kind of stuck there.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is like this:

Your Retry advice sends to the `failureChannel` from the `recoveryCallback` and exits, successfully.

Then when we look into the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` code, we see this logic:

```
 try {
        Object result = callback.execute();
        if (this.onSuccessExpression != null) {
            evaluateSuccessExpression(message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So, since there is no exception calling `callback`, it goes to the `successChannel` configured.

To make it fail and go to the `failureChannel` configured, you should consider to not use that `recoveryCallback`. Then `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` will throw an exception which is going to be caught by the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and sent to that `failureChannel`. There won't be `onSuccessExpression` evaluation since we will end up with an exception.